# Does JVM allow to create language with struct?

Tags: java, struct, garbage-collection

Does JVM allow to create language with struct? I mean the same struct as C# (and IL) has. The struct should be custom value type, therefore not target for garbage collector. Don't take me wrong I don't want Java to be the same as C# - I just want to learn some lesson from people who fully understand how and why Java and JVM designed. What's the motivation of not having it? Was introducing struct considered at any point by Java community or Sun/Oracle? Do you know any links to the stories around it?

**CONCLUSION:**
SO is not a right place to ask this question. Because there are no people who related to that decision about 20 years ago. Although some reasonable SO users provided below following possible reasons for not having custom value types (structs) in order they appeared:

1. Custom value types would affect simplicity of JVM implementation.
2. Value types are against OOP principles which Java tries to follow.
3. Learning curve. Everything-is-a-reference-object languages are
   easier to learn.

Comment: About Date: it means what it says: should Date be reference or value (primitive) type? If it's value type then it's not GC'ed. Well, I want to understand motivation. Knowing that someone chose something different then me is not enough for me. I'm certanly less experienced then devs who architectured Java and continue to drive it's development. I want to learn from other's decisions. For that I need to see motivation behind these decisions. So far "simplicity of JVM" is the only one argument for not having structs.

Comment: Motivation is even more important then the decision. Because it allows to reconsider decisions that were done in past. For example, I could rephrase my question to: "Why not to introduce structs to JVM?". Then the fact that someone decided not to do it several years ago doesn't mean anything. All pros and cons should be considered again and decision should be made. According from what I see on the web there're a lot of devs (especially from gamedev) who would be glad to have structs. And I don't see how it breaks life of reference types lovers - they still will have them (including Date).

Comment: It's not *simplicity* why there are no structs in Java - they are not necessary by design because structs don't fit into the object oriented concept of Java. And OO is not about saving memory or being easy to use in this or that project. OO is about dividing the code into "independent", versatile "Objects" that we can extend, adjust and reuse in other programs (without needing to know how it works).

Comment: @vladimir: +1 this is really a very interesting discussion!

Comment: @GameDroids I saw one of your comments: it seems that you're saying that there shouldn't be primitive types at all (including int, boolean, long and double). If missing struct is driven by OO concept of Java - then yes, I would agree. So other point is: value(primitive) type are against OOP.

Comment: @vladimir: yes, exactly! Even when I like the "easy" use of primitives, they are one of the things that shouldn't be necessary in a OO language. They break with the whole concept.

Comment: @vladimir If you're asking for discussion then you have your close reason. The purpose of SO is to answer questions factually, not to exchange opinions on a topic, and this very much is a matter of opinion. And nobody here can answer questions about the motivations of an unknown person 20 years ago factually unless they're a matter of record.

Comment: @GameDroids A discussion, no matter how interesting, doesn't belong here. There's plenty of venues more appropriate for it.

Comment: @millimoose I agree. So here you mention not only JVM implementation simplicity but also learning curve. +1 for this. That I would buy too. Specifically on Python: I was able to teach some non-tech at all people to program in Python. And that was a showcase for me how these reference-only langs are easier to learn. Although dichotomy was there from the beginning - primitive types aren't suggested by me, int, double - there were there from the beginning.

Comment: @vladimir Now you're just being a jerk. I (and a bunch of other people) am humouring you and engaging in a conversation on what the problems with this question are instead of just voting, moving on, and letting you rant in an echo chamber. And you feel the right reaction is to twist that against me to get the last word? I suppose you're right, I'll nuke my chatty contributions, go have a discussion elsewhere.

Comment: @millimoose Sorry, I didn't want to offend you. I fully understand that SO isn't a place for discussions, although I don't how how they have been started. My question might be answered in 3 lines of text (check the updated question). If you know better place where such questions are asked and answered - please advise. I would rather move there. Otherwise I don't see why it's good to shut othe people's mouth in already closed (by you too) question.

Comment: @vladimir Then your question should ideally be shorter, and contain less sentences that are questions. Honestly after this many updates I have no idea what you're asking anymore. If you believe there's a kernel to it that may be answered factually (i.e. not with opinions), **by people who frequent SO** (of whom it's not very likely anyone is an authority on the design of Java or the JVM, or can influence said design in any way), feel free to ask a new question, while making sure you *stay on point*. (You have to admit that over this many updates and comments your point pretty much got lost.)

Comment: @vladimir So, a bad question would be "Why doesn't Java have structs?" (The only answers you can get are "we don't really know", "because nobody in charge of Java put them in".) Same for "Could Java eventually grow structs?" (A: "We can't predict the future, and only the people in charge of Java can do anything else.") Or "Are structs that much bother that there's a good reason to leave them out?" (This is subjective and argumentative and asking people to defend a choice somebody else made ages ago. Java *and* C# are both successful, so they're neither too much bother nor a necessity.)

Comment: @millimoose Thanks. I shortened my question to the real core. I don't see how this question might be asked at all on SO given all your restrictions. I don't see how questions like these might be asked without being closed at all. Although some reasonable opinions I have got are important to me and I think that I've got what I was looking for - so I don't need to ask another questions. If SO doesn't like my way of asking this question, SO probably will wipe out this question altogether with my account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Except for primitives, Java doesn't have 'Value types' similar to C#.  I can only guess why it was designed this way; probably for simplicity.  Primitives are not objects likely for performance reasons.

Comment: Yes, it is actually a good question, why there are *primitives* in an Object Oriented language.

Comment: The reality of performance.  A 32 bit int needs only 4 bytes and is easily copied, cached, used in machine instructions etc.  An integer object would need extra space for housekeeping.

Comment: Simplicity, yes. That's at least some motivation. Marking as an answer for now. Any other arguments?

Answer (score 4):

I think it would theoretically *possible* to introduce a struct-like, *not* garbage collected type in Java. But, since Java has no pointers (and will never have), that struct-like thing should be always passed by value, like a primitive.

The main advantage would be the one of creating large arrays of this value types without each item of the array having its own lifecycle (and garbage collection burden).

You might find interesting this 10 years old discussion about the introduction of structs (trivial data objects) in Java: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4820062

Comment: +1 for the link. Of course, there're some ways to implement this. I'm interested how it was decided not to implement it at all. When it comes to rapid development somehow these open source "communities" seems to be not able to agree on anything. Even when it absolutely makes sense to implement at least something. That's the phenomenon applied to this struct case I'm interested in.

Comment: It's a pity that key people are not here. May be someone close to the decision will take a look at question. I aggree with you. Obviously simplicity of JVM implementation would be affected with introduction of struct. That's a tradeoff. Again saying that community was able to aggree on not having struct is only OK when pros and cons were put on a table, discussed and final decision somehow voted or accepted by some community's decision procedure.

Comment: @vladimir: if you think of it for a minute, you see that structs will affect several other concepts. For example, you should think of a way for passing a struct by reference, because it's unacceptable to pass structs only by value since it would increase the call stack without control. And this ends up with something that resembles pointers (and Java dropped them since the first version). Language design is not for the people. :) If some decisions are taken, then there's a point. They don't just add elements to a language like ingredients to a salad.

Comment: @gd1 Increasing call stack without control is some scary tale that should be checked with C# programmers. They DO have custom value types and their stack is still under control. Your statement about pointers is also questionable for me - again, take a look at C#. Defiantly I aggree that "Language design is not for people". If language designers would think about programmers on their language as about their clients then we probably would see more programmer-friendly langs and possible with no big downsides (not bigger then we have now).

Comment: I know about C# "value types". They're interesting. But they match with a totally different language design if compared to Java. Were you asking if it is feasible to put some struct-like thing into Java, or how to turn Java into C#? In C# can you pass by reference even an int, in Java you can't. Introducing this feature is like making another language, I think.
And C# value types are not "for free". They are a small "inconsistency" in the OO world and so need to be boxed and unboxed in some (untrivial) situations, with significant impact. Look a the whole picture, not only your desires. ;)

Comment: And please be constructive. Discussions about language design (or "language wars") always end up in some pointless argument like "language X is better of language Y because it has Z. Why don't we put Z into Y?". That's why they are proactively closed. :)

Comment: I'm trying my best to be constructive. I intentionally moved from C# to Java recently. I just meant that "stack out of control" isn't something you will 100% get with custom value types. Not even 1%. I agree struct aren't given at zero cost in C# nor even at relatively small cost. Although IL designers found it to be useful enough for adding them to IL. Many devs are enjoying them. So for me it's reasonable question if the language (or VM) isn't freezed why not to consider adding it. That won't make Java to be the same as C#. There're too many other diffs.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly doubt that JVM prevents this in any way as far as custom languages are concerned. It just doesn't really help. You'd have to convert struct-typed local variables into a bunch of name-mangled primitive-typed local variables, handle (un)boxing for storing them in collections and interacting with Java libraries, and generally come up with and implement all value-type semantics from scratch

Comment: An array of value-types would likely perform well in a container since it would have good locality of reference.

Comment: @seand It might, but then your language would also have to implement its own array and/or container types, the Java ones certainly wouldn't work. The `newarray` and `anewarray` opcodes only allow you to allocate arrays of primitive and reference types. So you'd also have to convert language constructs into operations over parallel arrays, or packing/unpacking from a byte array, or whatever. (I'm kind of at my limits of programming language design/implementation knowledge here so I might be off the mark entirely.)

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the JVM internals but that sounds right.  It would likely have to be modified to support true value type arrays larger than the biggest existing primitive (a long?).  I think dotnet may already have support for this.

Comment: @seand I'm even less familiar with .NET internals than with the JVM ones, but since they had value types since day 1, and use reified generics, I'd wager a guess they have solid support for this somewhere. The C# compiler certainly does a lot more work as far as generating complex code on the fly is concerned than the Java one.

Answer (score -1):

The C `struct` is comparable to the Java `Objects`. In a `struct` you can pack several *complex* or *primitive* datatypes into one *complex* datatype, which is in Java a `class` or `Object`.

Now, the way you want to use that Object is up to you. You can pack it with public variables or you can give it some more *functions* / *methods* to handle those variables.  The whole idea behind all this is that (unlike C languages) Java was created as an Object Oriented language from the beginning (ok, there are some minor aspects in Java that are not really part of OO, like the primitives boolean, int etc.. but thats another story).

And concerning the `garbage collector`, well that's something in Java a *normal* programmer shouldn't (have to) worry about. If and when an Object is subject to garbage collection is up to the runtime. (Although it is possible to force garbage collection, which is not very practical).

Comment: Do you really think that "normal programmer" should never think about memory management during programming on Java? Or you just meant that it's so rare when you really care about memory management in Java because in most cases it just works? Have you ever participated in projects with zero (or close to it) runtime memory allocations? Any experience with high-frequency data flying over some transport? Or the one shouldn't be "normal" to work on this? What do you think?

Comment: @GameDroid I agree that Java Objects looks like structs in that you can have data members etc.  However object and structs (in a C sense) have significantly different semantics.

Comment: @vladimir Yes and no. Sorry, *normal programmer* is very ambiguous. Of course there are cases where it is most essential to care about memory (and yes, I participated in such projects - like Chipcards etc). But I was not talking about programming an "airplane autopilot". Java is a *high level* programming language, which means it is designed to run under a Operation Systems that *must* take care of memory management itself. Such a programmer should never make assumptions on how much memory the machine has or which other program might be running - this is the job of the OS.

Comment: @GameDroids Sadly, but that's the reality in my second in a row project I found myself thinking of garbage collection a lot. One was C# GUI app, another is Java server app. It might be just because I'm working in the area which is tend to be high-frequency, low-latency (investment banking). But in my last 5 years experience I had to think about memory management and then I started asking myself - is it good concept at all - Garbage Collection? Well I'm not saying it's bad. I'm thinking...

Comment: @vladimir: when your program is running in a *very* confined space, where you are absolutely sure about the resources you can use: then yes,  *garbage collection* is ineffective. But let's have a look inside: first there is the CPU translating *complex instructions* into into hard coded operations. Above that, there is the CMOS translating Assembler into machine code, above that there is the OS-core managing programs and resources, above that there is the rest of the OS, above that there is our program (or a VM)- I think those levels *beneath* us are way more effective in resource management.